# How should define a polynomial in Python 3.7.4

Tags: python-3.x

I have the error in the scalar multiply and power method. I tried everything but the result always an error. Which method should fix ???

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
class Poly:
    def __init__(self,coefficients):
        self.coefficients = list(coefficients)
    def __call__(self,x):
        res = 0
        for i in range(len(self.coefficients)):
            res += self.coefficients[i] * x**i
        return res
    def add(self,p):
        (coefficients1, coefficients2) = (self.coefficients, p.coefficients)
        if(len(coefficients1)>len(coefficients2)):
            (coefficients1, coefficients2) = (coefficients2, coefficients1)

        coefficients1 = [0]*(len(coefficients2)>len(coefficients1))+coefficients1

        coefficients = [coefficients1[i] + coefficients2[i] for i in range(len(coefficients1))]
        return Poly(coefficients)
    def scalar_multiply(self,n):
        np.array(list(coefficients))
        return np.array(list(coefficients))**n

    def multiply(self,p):
        a = self.coefficients
        b = p.coefficients
        M = len(a)-1
        N = len(b)-1
        result_coeff = np.zeroes(M+N+1)
        for i in range(0,M+1):
            for j in range(0,N+1):
                result_coeff[i+j] += a[i]*b[j]
        return Poly(result_coeff)
    def power(self,n):
        return np.array(list(coefficients))**n

    def diff(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self.coefficients)):
            self.coefficients[i-1] = i*self.coefficients[i]
        del self.coefficients[-1]
    def integrate(self):
        i = quad(diff,0,x)
        print(i[x])
    def eval(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(self.coefficients)-1,0,-1):
            sum+=self.coeffs[i]*(x**i)
        return sum(coeff * x**exp for exp, coeff in enumerate(reversed(self.coefficients)))

    def print(self):
        print(res)
```

Comment: Post the exact error with trace, [edit]ed into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The most immediate problem with the functions you mention is that they try to use a variable `coefficients` that has not been defined in them. You probably want to be using `self.coefficients` instead.

That said, there are a lot of other issues in your code (such as returning different types unexpectedly), so just fixing this one problem probably won't lead to your code working correctly, but you can try to address each other issue as you get to them.